# Java If statements inside for loop, returning multiple int values.

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to return the four int values. I keep getting unreachable statement errors probably because of the if statements?

It's supposed to return 4 values, or the numbers of upper case , lower case etc in a the string. I tried printing each variable out and it prints, but doesn't return them the way it is now.

```
public static int category(String pw)
{
    int Upper = 0;
    int lower =0;
    int num = 0;
    int symbol=0;

    for (int i=0; i< pw.length(); i++)
    {
        if (65 <= pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)<=90)
        {
            Upper++;

        } 

        if(97<= pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i) <=122)
        {
            lower++;

        }

        if(48<= pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i) < 57)
        {
            num++;

        }


        if (31 < pw.charAt(i) &&  pw.charAt(i) < 48 || 57 < pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)< 64 || 90 < pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)< 97 || 122 < pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)< (127) + 1)
        {
            symbol++;

        }


    }
    return Upper;
    return lower;
    return num;
    return symbol;
}
```

Comment: you should either create a class or make an array and return

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply have four return statements in a method.

What are you doing with these variables after you return them? Maybe consider storing them into an array or another data structure and returning that if it's fits your needs.

Comment: Technically, you **can** have four return statements in a method, but only one can actually be executed. (Having four return statements for four different conditions is ok)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you cannot return multiple values like that. When the first `return` is reached the method `return`s. It is also the source of the "unreachable code" issue; any code appearing after a `return` statement that is not conditional will be unreachable.

There are plenty of solutions for this such as returning an array or some other data structure of the data which may be quick and easy but if it were me I'd create a class to hold or process the data. Here's *one* take on this idea:

```
public class Category {

    private int upper;
    private int lower;
    private int num;
    private int symbol;

    // Getters and Setter for your private data
    // ...

    // Default constructor
    public Category() {...}

    // Copy constructor
    public Category (Category cat) {...}

    // Constructor good for the method
    public Category (int upper, int lower, int num, int symbol) {...}

    public static Category getCategory(String pw)
    {
        // Everything else is the same
        // ...

        // Here's the important part
        // This will return a new instance of the Category object
        return new Category(Upper, lower, num, symbol);
    }
```

You will call this in your code like so => `Category category = Category.getCategory(yourString);`
If it turns out that you don't need the data to persist and have multiple strings to categorize you can keep track of one `Category` instance and do `category = Category.getCategory(yourOtherString);`.

You will access the data in category like => `category.getUpper();`, `category.getLower();`, ... via the public getters and setters you created in the class.

Here you have everything in a compact object that makes sense as opposed as an array or list etc;
I also followed your code in that `Upper` is capitalized in your method while the others are not. I'd probably avoid that. Pick a convention to follow and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return mulitple `ints` at once. If you want to do that you need an `array` and this must also be defined in the function's header.

Answer (score 0):

**you can return a List as i have mentioned below:**

```
public static List<Integer> category(String pw)
    {
        int Upper = 0;
        int lower =0;
        int num = 0;
        int symbol=0;
    List<Integer> allInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i=0; i< pw.length(); i++)
        {
            if (65 <= pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)<=90)
            {
                Upper++;

            } 

            if(97<= pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i) <=122)
            {
                lower++;

            }

            if(48<= pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i) < 57)
            {
                num++;

            }


            if (31 < pw.charAt(i) &&  pw.charAt(i) < 48 || 57 < pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)< 64 || 90 < pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)< 97 || 122 < pw.charAt(i) && pw.charAt(i)< (127) + 1)
            {
                symbol++;

            }


        }

    allInts.add(0, Upper);
    allInts.add(1,lower)
    allInts.add(2,num)
    allInts.add(3,symbol)

       return allInts; // returning list

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will at most execute one `return` statement in a method as it not only returns the variable but also terminates the method. If you put multiple `return` statements after each other only the first one will be executed as after this you will leave the method.